# Designing the pivot point for a swingarm

Tags: mechanical-engineering, design

I came up with the following design for a single wheel trailer:

[image: Single wheel trailer]

[image: Single wheel trailer]

The shock absorber is missing in this drawing.

What is the best way to mount the swingarm to the horizontal plate? It needs to pivot.

I was thinking about pillow blocks, but I'm not sure if they are suitable for this application. Design should be as simple as possible and easy to fabricate.

Comment: Some further detail would be helpful here, along the lines of labeling the parts of your drawing and maybe providing a picture/link to the pillow blocks you are suggesting.

Comment: My first thought was also pillow blocks. Could you please elaborate on why you think they might not be appropriate? Do you need something more like a ball joint for an additional degree of freedom? Or, do you need a fixed joint for one less degree of freedom?

Comment: How much movement are you realistically going to see? I think pillow blocks might be a bit much. Given the size of the wheel and the minimalist brackets the load can't be all that high... I'd consider just welding on two tabs with holes drilled through them and bolting it together with the appropriate spacers and bolt (one that is not threaded where it will be pivoting around)

Comment: The plate looks flimsy right now. It is going to take some torsional loading which might break the welds if it is not strong enough.

Answer (score 1):

I would have drilled 2 holes in a bracket and then welded it onto the flat plate.

To reduce friction and absorb high frequency vibrations, I would have then used cheap nylon bushings.

[image]

Choose a bolt with a smaller diameter than that of the holes of the swing-arm. Now the space that would be left hollow in between the bolt and the holes should be filled with the nylon bushings mentioned above.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Rubber or plastic bushes are the conventional solution for suspension mountings. They cope well with shock loading and vibration, help to isolate vibration from  the wheels and are reasonable tolerant of slight misalignment.

Usually mounted as a press fit in a simple tubular housing with a bolt providing the connection to the suspension arm.